# CORS issue loading an external local GeoJSON into OpenLlayers 5

Tags: openlayers, geojson, cors

I have a local folder on my network with my HTML file and two subfolders, one with the downloaded folder from OpenLayers (renamed ol) and the other with my GeoJSON file (data). When I try to load the HTML file in Chrome, I get a CORS error. Why do I get this even though the document is loading everything from the same file? Is there any way to load it with a JS file like you can with Leaflet? Here is my code:

```
<div id=map class=map><div>
        <script src="ol/ol.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                url: 'data/Hydrant.GeoJSON',
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            });

            var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: vectorSource
                });

            var map = new ol.Map({
                target: 'map',
                layers: [
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                        source: new ol.source.OSM()
                    }),
                    vectorLayer
                ],
                view: new ol.View({
                    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-71.24, 42.06]),
                    zoom: 12
                })
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can find answers to using Chrome and file protocol xhr on Stackoverflow, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file  Alternatively you can use another browser such as Edge which treats file protocol differently, or set up localhost to avoid using file protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only experimenting locally, one possibility is to edit your `Hydrant.GeoJSON` file and define geojson as JS object by adding `var geojsonObject =` at the beginning, rename file to `Hydrant.GeoJSON.js` and include it as JS code:

```
<script src="data/Hydrant.GeoJSON.js"></script>
```

Then you define your vector source as

```
var vectorSource = new ol.Source.Vector({
  features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
});
```